# how to match a specific word outside of parentheses and ignore the word in parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regex to process a text string like:

```
select t2.f1 as rf1, (select t1.f1 from table1 t1  where t1.f1 = t2.f2) as rff, t2.f3 as rf3 FROM table2 t2
```

There are two "from" in the above string. One is in parenthesis and the other one is outside of parenthesis.  I would like to get the matched text just before the second "from":

```
select t2.f1 as rf1, (select t1.f1 from table1 t1  where t1.f1 = t2.f2) as rff, t2.f3 as rf3
```

My testing python regular expression is:

```
^\s*select\s+(?P<SELECTED>.+?)\s+from
```

which returns: `SELECTED    t2.f1 as rf1, (select t1.f1`

Anybody knows how to modify the regex to get `SELECTED  t2.f1 as rf1, (select t1.f1 from table1 t1  where t1.f1 = t2.f2) as rff, t2.f3 as rf3`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You need a greedy `+`, remove the `?`, and use `re.I` flag.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
^\s*select\s+(?P<SELECTED>.+?)\s+(from).*?(?=FROM)
```

you can try here it's find the full match
[online regex](https://regex101.com/r/JlkyoL/1)

and if you know that you always 2 select and from

you can use this

```
^\s*select.*(from).*?(?=FROM)
```

you can see [optiion 2](https://regex101.com/r/yFamT0/1)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Beny Gj.  How about the case: there are zero or more parentheses with "from" in this sql query?   I  test your regular expression, it works for 1, 2 or 3 pairs of parentheses with a "from",   but not for zero parentheses case.   Any hint?  Thanks a lot .

Comment: I think I found the solution with    ^\s*select\s+(?P<SELECTED>.+?)\s+(from)?.*?(?=FROM).    Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in python3.7:

```
 pat1     = "^\s*select\s+(?P<SELECTED>.*(from)*)\s+(?=from)"
 selected = re.compile(pat1, ((re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL) | re.MULTILINE))

 txt = "select t2.f1 as rf1, (select t1.f1 from table1 t1  where t1.f1 = t2.f2) as rff, t2.f3 as rf3 FROM table2 t2"
 selected.match(txt)
```

Thanks for the help @Beny Gj.